# Oracle: stragg and wm_concat return data in the incorrect order

Tags: oracle

Without `stragg` I get a listing of fourteen rows. When I introduce either `stragg` or `wm_concat` the content of the first row is not appearing at the front of the list. I'm using `stragg` in a number of places in my application and I'm now concerned that I may not be getting the expected results.

Could this be related to the width of the column of the data prior to it being concatenated?

When I use `stragg` against a listing of numbers I get exactly what I expect, it's only with text that I've discovered it's sorting data incorrectly. This is most disturbing. It shouldn't be relevant but I'm running the queries in TOAD using the 11g connect dll.

EDIT:
When I reduce the number of items to the first three the first item is at the front of  the list, when I add a fourth item it gets pushed to the end of the list. With additional items introduced it winds up second from last. I would not have expected that `stragg` would change the order of the list during the process.

Comment: Can you please post sample data, you try to concat?

Comment: And, since `stragg` is a custom user-defined aggregate function, can you post the particular implementation that you're using?  I'm assuming you've grabbed on of the implementations from AskTom but Tim Hall also has an implementation and others have created clones.  I wouldn't be shocked if some implementation out there had a bug but  missing the first row seems like an unlikely bug since it would be the easiest thing to see.

Comment: What _exact_ version of Oracle are you using; WM_CONCAT is a deprecated undocumented function and there are better things out there now...

Comment: I've made substantial edits to your post based on your most recent edit since it appears that the problem is solely with ordering not with the presence or absence of data in the list.  Please verify that I have not introduced any inaccuracies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stragg` is a user-defined aggregate function.  Various folks (Tom Kyte, Tim Hall, and many others) have written various versions of that function.  Not knowing which of these functions you started with or what customizations you made to it, I'll have to speculate a bit.  In general, though, those functions are not doing any sort of internal sort so the order that values appear in the list is arbitrary.  It would be perfectly valid for the function to return one order today and a different order tomorrow or for the order to be different in different sessions.

Various people have also written user-defined aggregate functions that return lists of data in a sorted order.  For example, Gary Myers has a [variant of the `stragg` function that sorts the elements alphabetically](http://blog.sydoracle.com/2005/12/new-variant-on-stragg-ordered.html).  You could use that and customize the function to sort the results by whatever you'd like to sort them by.

If you are using Oracle 11.2 or later, though, you'd be much better off using the [`LISTAGG` analytic function](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques.php#listagg) which makes it much easier to specify (or change) the way you are sorting data.

Comment: I'll just have to wait 'til we get to 11g and in the meantime I'll just do it the old fashioned way, in a code loop.